# pycharm says taht it cant find tensorflow.keras but it works

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

it always says tat it tf.keras is an "Unresolved References" but it works. why and how can i get to reconize it?

I tryed using

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

and

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras
```

but then it just wont work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `tensorflow` version do you use? There is a known issue with 2.0.0 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37589

Comment: i use 2.0 sorry for the late answer

Answer (score -1):

You have to set your projects' python interpreter to the one that you are using.

Try to change it in `File->settings->Project->project interpreter` and then select the python from the environment where you have tensorflow installed